# Excel - referencing values from another file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'd like to use my Excel reports in another Excel file.

I know I can just reference the file, but then it's impossible to use the data without opening the other file as well and I have about 30 files that I need to use.

So I'd like to reference the data from these files in functions, without needing to have the other files open.

Please advise what's the best way to approach this so I can update the values from other Excel files easily.

Suppose I have files: A. and B and I want to calculate in A a formula for `=sum(B.#column1)`, without the need to have the file open at the time, and with the possibility to refresh data.

Comment: `='C:\whichever filepath\[whichever file name.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1`

Comment: Hello, unfortunately im asking for an alternative solution, because this way its not updating unless the other workbook is open, and i need to work with above 30 work books

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this done is writing whatever formula you need, while having the file you want to reference open.

When you get to the part where you want to reference the other cell while writing your formula, simply click on that cell in the other workbook. It's path and reference will be automatically added to your formula, and will be updated even if the workbook is closed.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately im asking for an alternative solution, because this way its not updating unless the other workbook is open, and i need to work with above 30 work books

Comment: [please read this](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-21e995b5-bab1-4328-8ab3-dd357fe0e653) to automatically update external links without having to open all files. Excel has got you covered.

Comment: That is your opinion i see. however please try it yourself. if you update with the file closed it will not update!

Comment: I have tried this several times before recommending it to you, I test my answers thoroughly, and it works every time. It will either prompt for you to enable automatic update of links, or allow you to click manual update of links. If not, there might be an issue with either the file or your access to it.

Comment: Have you checked your references are definitely correct? Also what happens [when you try to force it with vba?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.updatelink)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another question similar to yours that has some ideas on how to mitigate this problem.

https://superuser.com/questions/1190809/how-to-update-automatically-and-continuously-cell-values-in-the-master-workbook

Unfortunately there isn't a super clean solution but the ideas listed at the link should certainly minimize your problems.